# Permission error when configuring credential rotation in AWS Secret Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I'm following this [document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/) to configure the credential rotaion, but I got this error:

```
Fail to rotate the secret "xxxxxxxx"
Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com
```

I'm using the developer role instead of a root user, I'm just wondering how can I resolve this issue and enable the rotation?

I have a potential solution, maybe I can create a Lambda function manually and select 'Use an existing Lambda function to perform rotation' in Secret Manager? But I feel like I will probably still get the same permission issue. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant Secrets Manager permission to invoke the policy - See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-secrets-manager/

'Grant Secrets Manager permission to call the function on your behalf'

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. My database is RDS with Auraro MySQL engine, I think Secrets Manager has the built-in feature to envoke the function automatically? I read the article you metioned, it says 'Secrets created with Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) supported databases automatically create the Lambda rotation, ' why I have to grant the permission to tell secret manager to call the function even if I'm uing a supported database?

Comment: @Cecilia If you go through the secrets manager console to create that rotation lambda, that permission will get attached automatically. Since I believe that you're writing a custom lambda, you need to do this step manually

Comment: Hi I've tried to configure secrets manager to create Lambda automatically in the console but it gave me error, saying I haven't grant SM permission to invoke the function, that's why I'm trying to create a rotation Lambda manually.

Comment: The link you mentioned is for unsupported database, since I'm using Aurora MySQL, I found this function template (https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSMySQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py), just not sure which part I should modify to grant secret manager access permission to invoke the Lambda function, any thoughts?

Comment: @Cecilia you don't need to modify the function. If you created it through the secrets manager console, it should already have that permission